# Grafana variables

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Can someone explain what "on(instance)" refers to in this string)? I can see that $instance refers to variables for the dashboard. "on()" is a function right, but plain "instance" I cannot understand what it points to.

```
100 - (java_lang_operatingsystem_freephysicalmemorysize{instance=~"$instance"} / on(instance) java_lang_operatingsystem_totalphysicalmemorysize{instance=~"$instance"} *100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, how dumb (copy-paste). I was trying a new diagram but I just copied it and verified the variable but I did not hit MatchCase. the word memory is supposed to be capitalized and it finds it in the scraped variables. So that tells me that "instance" is the result of 100 - variable from $instance.

Comment: By the way change this variable in your exporter config file and it will work right from the start.

    lowercaseOutputName: true